# Why is writing a closed TCP socket worse than reading one?

Tags: language-agnostic, sockets, network-programming, network-protocols

When you read a closed TCP socket you get a regular error, i.e. it either returns 0 indicating EOF or -1 and an error code in `errno` which can be printed with [`perror`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/perror.html).

However, when you write a closed TCP socket the OS sends `SIGPIPE` to your app which will terminate the app if not caught.

Why is writing the closed TCP socket worse than reading it?

Comment: there's something else going on here that's fairly subtle: a TCP connection can be half closed, meaning one side has closed the socket (sent a FIN packet), but the other side still has data to send. If you're going rooting around at this level, please read: http://superuser.com/questions/298919/what-is-tcp-half-open-connection-and-tcp-half-closed-connection

Answer (score 12, accepted):

+1 To [Greg Hewgill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216374/why-is-writing-a-closed-tcp-socket-worse-than-reading-one/2216386#2216386) for leading my thought process in the correct direction to find the answer.

The real reason for `SIGPIPE` in both sockets and pipes is the filter idiom / pattern which applies to typical I/O in Unix systems.

Starting with pipes. Filter programs like grep typically write to `STDOUT` and read from `STDIN`, which may be redirected by the shell to a pipe.  For example:

```
cat someVeryBigFile | grep foo | doSomeThingErrorProne
```

The shell when it forks and then exec's these programs probably uses the [`dup2`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup2) system call to redirect `STDIN`, `STDOUT` and `STDERR` to the appropriate pipes.

Since the filter program `grep` doesn't know and has no way of knowing that it's output has been redirected then the only way to tell it to stop writing to a broken pipe if `doSomeThingErrorProne` crashes is with a signal since return values of writes to `STDOUT` are rarely if ever checked.

The analog with sockets would be the [`inetd`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inetd) server taking the place of the shell.

As an example I assume you could turn `grep` into a network service which operates over `TCP` sockets.  For example with `inetd` if you want to have a `grep` server on `TCP` port 8000 then add this to `/etc/services`:

```
grep     8000/tcp   # grep server
```

Then add this to `/etc/inetd.conf`:

```
grep  stream tcp nowait root /usr/bin/grep grep foo
```

Send `SIGHUP` to `inetd` and connect to port 8000 with telnet.  This should cause `inetd` to fork, dup the socket onto `STDIN`, `STDOUT` and `STDERR` and then exec `grep` with foo as an argument.   If you start typing lines into telnet `grep` will echo those lines which contain foo.

Now replace telnet with a program named `ticker` that for instance writes a stream of real time stock quotes to `STDOUT` and gets commands on `STDIN`.  Someone telnets to port 8000 and types "start java" to get quotes for Sun Microsystems.  Then they get up and go to lunch.  telnet inexplicably crashes.  If there was no `SIGPIPE` to send then `ticker` would keep sending quotes forever, never knowing that the process on the other end had crashed, and needlessly wasting system resources.

Answer (score 10):

Usually if you're writing to a socket, you would expect the other end to be listening. This is sort of like a telephone call - if you're speaking, you wouldn't expect the other party to simply hang up the call.

If you're reading from a socket, then you're expecting the other end to either (a) send you something, or (b) close the socket. Situation (b) would happen if you've just sent something like a QUIT command to the other end.

Comment: But that doesn't really tell me why `write` or `send` can't just return an error directly the same way `read` or `recv` do.  Why whack the app over the head with `SIGPIPE` like that?  There's got to be some deeper reason for such an extreme response by the OS. Say I've got a socket that just received a `RST`.  If I `read` it I get -1 with ECONNRESET, why not just get the same thing when I write?  In both cases I'm expecting to engage in consensual I/O and not getting what I expected.

Comment: @Robert: The typical use case for pipe input and output on Unix was historically for "filter" programs, that read from an input pipe and write to an output pipe (the `grep` program is such an example). In order to make such a filter terminate immediately when the output is no longer listening, the `SIGPIPE` signal default behaviour was set to terminate the program. Without this, the filter would continue writing to the output until its input was exhausted (which could be a while).

Comment: Tell me if this sounds right:  The real reason for `SIGPIPE` is that filter programs like grep typically write to `STDOUT`, which may be redirected by the shell to a pipe.  Since the filter program doesn't know and has no way of knowing that it's output has been redirected then the only way to tell it to stop writing to a broken pipe is with a signal since return values of writes to `STDOUT` are rarely checked.  The analog with sockets would be `inetd` accepting a connection, spawning the server and `dup2` ing the socket onto `STDIN`,`STDOUT`,`STDERR`!

Comment: @Robert: Yes, it sounds like you've got it.

Answer (score 7):

Think of the socket as a big pipeline of data between the sending and the receiving process.  Now imagine that the pipeline has a valve that is shut (the socket connection is closed).

If you're reading from the socket (trying to get something out of the pipe), there's no harm in trying to read something that isn't there; you just won't get any data out.  In fact, you may, as you said, get an EOF, which is correct, as there's no more data to be read.

However, *writing* to this closed connection is another matter.  Data won't go through, and you may wind up dropping some important communication on the floor.  (You can't send water down a pipe with a closed valve; if you try, something will probably burst somewhere, or, at the very least, the back pressure will spray water all over the place.)  That's why there's a more powerful tool to alert you to this condition, namely, the SIGPIPE signal.

You can always ignore or block the signal, but you do so at your own risk.

Answer (score 3):

I think a large part of the answer is 'so that a socket behaves rather similarly to a classic Unix (anonymous) pipe'.  Those also exhibit the same behaviour - witness the name of the signal.

So, then it is reasonable to ask why do pipes behave that way.  Greg Hewgill's answer gives a summary of the situation.

Another way of looking at it is - what is the alternative?  Should a 'read()' on a pipe with no writer give a SIGPIPE signal?  The meaning of SIGPIPE would have to change from 'write on a pipe with noone to read it', of course, but that's trivial.  There's no particular reason to think that it would be better; the EOF indication (zero bytes to read; zero bytes read) is a perfect description of the state of the pipe, and so the behaviour of read is good.

What about 'write()'?  Well, an option would be to return the number of bytes written - zero.  But that is not a good idea; it implies that the code should try again and maybe more bytes would be sent, which is not going to be the case.  Another option would be an error - write() returns -1 and sets an appropriate errno.  It isn't clear that there is one.  EINVAL or EBADF are both inaccurate: the file descriptor is correct and open at this end (and should be closed after the failing write); there just isn't anything to read it.  EPIPE means 'broken PIPE'; so, with a caveat about "this is a socket, not a pipe", it would be the appropriate error.  It is probably the errno returned if you ignore SIGPIPE.  It would be feasible to do this - just return an appropriate error when the pipe is broken (and never send the signal).  However, it is an empirical fact that many programs do not pay as much attention to where their output is going, and if you pipe a command that will read a multi-gigabyte file into a process that quits after the first 20 KB, but it is not paying attention to the status of its writes, then it will take a long time to finish, and will be wasting machine effort while doing so, whereas by sending it a signal that it is not ignoring, it will stop quickly -- this is definitely advantageous.  And you can get the error if you want it.  So the signal sending has benefits to the o/s in the context of pipes; and sockets emulate pipes rather closely.

Interesting aside: while checking the message for SIGPIPE, I found the socket option:

```
#define SO_NOSIGPIPE 0x1022 /* APPLE: No SIGPIPE on EPIPE */
```

Comment: So basically you're saying that `SIGPIPE` exists because lots of programmers ignore error codes in the case of write which could cause the process to hog system resources when it's not actually accomplishing anything?  Or to put it another way, people are more meticulous about checking their input than their output and that's the reason for the asymmetry in `read` and `write`?

Comment: @Robert: yes, basically.  People tend to write their code on the assumption that the output device won't go away, or run out of space.  When the output is a pipe and the receiving program stops reading before the end of the output, it is important to ensure that the writing program pays attention.  And this is a simple mechanism that leaves programs simpler to write.

Comment: So was there a time that pre-dated `SIGPIPE`?  Since you're saying this is to certain extent a result of user / programmer bad behavior, was there once a version of Unix that returned an error when writing to a closed pipe and then they changed it to return a signal, or was `SIGPIPE` in there from the beginning in anticipation of bad behavior?

Comment: @Robert S. Barnes: pipe was added fairly early to Unix.  According to Dennis Ritchie in "The Evolution of the UNIX Time-sharing System", pipes were not available on the PDP-7 versions of UNIX, and were added to the PDP-11 version in 1972 (2-3 years after the first versions of UNIX).  (Ref: "UNIX® SYSTEM: Readings and Applications, Volume II", 1987.  This was a second edition of the AT&T (Bell) journal dedicated to Unix, and contains some interesting stuff.  It was published by Prentice-Hall as ISBN 0-13-939845-7 - http://www.amazon.com/Unix-System-Readings-Applications-UNIX-R/dp/0139398457)