# Unix TCP servers and UDP Servers

Tags: unix, tcp, network-programming, udp, client-server

Why is the design of TCP servers mostly such that whenever it accepts a connection, a new  process is invoked to handle it . But, why in the case of UDP servers, mostly there is only a single process that handles all client requests ?

Answer (score 3):

The main difference between TCP and UDP is, as stated before, that UDP is connectionless.

A program using UDP has only one socket where it receives messages. So there's no problem if you just block and wait for a message.

If using TCP you get one socket for every client which connects. Then you can't just block and wait for ONE socket to receive something, because there are other sockets which must be processed at the same time.
So you got two options, either use nonblocking methods or use threads. Code is usually much simpler when you don't have one while loop which has to handle every client, so threading is often prefered. You can also save some CPU time if using blocking methods.

Comment: Don't forget `select` - this allows the process to block, while still handling multiple TCP sessions within a single thread. High performance servers may adopt a hybrid approach, such as  Apache MPM< (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/worker.html).

Comment: Thx for the Link. Apache MPM prefork appears interesting.

Answer (score 1):

When you talk with client via TCP connection you maintain TCP session. So when new connection established you need separate process(or thread, no matter how it implemented and what OS used) and maintain conversation. But when you use UDP connection you may recieve datagram(and you will be informed about senders ip and port) but in common case you cannot respond on it.

Comment: Okay, Since 'a new process is created to handle every new connection that arrives at the server' . Won't the TCP server get overloaded if it creates a new process for every new connection ? How is it being managed ? Also, Consider a scenario that there are multiple connection requests are arriving while the TCP server is busy in the process of creation of a new process for the earlier connection request. How does the TCP server handle those multiple connection requests during that scenario ? Any ideas ?

Comment: @Karthik: of course it might get overloaded. That's why big websites have thousands of servers handling these requests instead of just one, and performance is a major concern in server design.

Comment: @Karthik Balaguru - One thread/process per connection only works up to a point before it becomes self-defeating.  Beyond that point you need to go to either multiplexing (e.g. select) or asynchronous method (e.g. "man -k aio_" to see that family).  When you get beyond that you have to use multiple servers, load balancing and such.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the classic Unix server paradigm is filter based.  For example, various network services can be configured in /etc/services and a program like inetd listens on all of the TCP and UDP sockets for incoming connections and datagrams.  When a connection / DG arrives it forks, redirects stdin, stdout and stderr to the socket using the dup2 system call, and then execs the server process.  [You can take any program which reads from stdin and writes to stdout and turn it into a network service, such as grep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216374/why-is-writing-a-closed-tcp-socket-worse-than-reading-one/2218360#2218360).

According to Steven's in "[Unix Network Programming](http://www.unpbook.com)", there are five kinds of server I/O models (pg. 154):

1. blocking
2. non-blocking
3. multiplexing (select and poll)
4. Signal Driven
5. asynchronous ( POSIX aio_ functions )

In addition the servers can be either Iterative or Concurrent.

You ask why are TCP servers are typically concurrent, while UDP servers are typically iterative.

The UDP side is easier to answer.  Typically UDP apps follow a simple request response model where a client sends a short request followed by a reply with each pair constituting a stand alone transaction.  UDP servers are the only ones which use Signal Drive I/O, and at the very rarely.

TCP is a bit more complicated.  Iterative servers can use any of the I/O models above, except #4.  The fastest servers on a single processor are actually Iterative servers using non-blocking I/O.  However, these are considered relatively complex to implement and that plus the Unix filter idiom where traditionally the primary reasons for use of the concurrent model with blocking I/O, whether multiprocess or multithreaded.  Now, with the advent of common multicore systems, the concurrent model also has the performance advantage.

Comment: I think, i need to check the 'Unix Network Programming' book from Steven for the various server model designs. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Your generalization is too general. This is a pattern you might see with a Unix-based server, where process creation is inexpensive. A .NET-based service will use a new thread from the thread pool instead of creating a new process.

Comment: Yes, i am talking about the Unix/Linux environment , but eager to know other views also.

Answer (score 0):

Programs that can continue to do useful work while they are waiting for I/O 
will often be multithreaded. Programs that do lots of computation which 
can be neatly divided into separate sections can benefit from 
multithreading, if there are multiple processors. Programs that service 
lots of network requests can sometimes benefit by having a pool of 
available threads to service requests. GUI programs that also need to 
perform computation can benefit from multithreading, because it allows the 
main thread to continue to service GUI events.

Thats why we use TCP as an internet protocol.