# What's the purpose of send(2) receiving a SIGPIPE?

Tags: c, linux, sockets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is writing a closed TCP socket worse than reading one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216374/why-is-writing-a-closed-tcp-socket-worse-than-reading-one)

Why doesn't an erroneous return value suffice?
What can I do in a signal handler that I can't do by testing the return value for EPIPE?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216374/why-is-writing-a-closed-tcp-socket-worse-than-reading-one (The accepted answer is a bit down, but explains the original purpose well. When you're explicittly dealing with TCP sockets it's common practice to set SIGPIPE to SIG_IGN and handle write/send returning -1)

Answer (score 1):

Back in the old days almost every signal caused a Unix program to terminate. Because inter-process communication by pipes is fundamental in Unix, `SIGPIPE` was intended to terminate programs which didn't handle `write(2)`/`read(2)` errors.

Suppose you have two processes communicating through a pipe. If one of them dies, one of the ends of the pipe isn't active anymore. `SIGPIPE` is intended to kill the other process as well.

As an example, consider:

```
cat myfile | grep find_something
```

If `cat` is killed in the middle of reading the file, `grep` simply doesn't have what to do anymore and is killed by a `SIGPIPE` signal. If no signal was sent and `grep` didn't check the return value of `read`, `grep` would misbehave in some way.

Answer (score 0):

As with many other things, my guess is that it was just a design choice someone made that eventually made it into the POSIX standards and has remained till date. That someone may have thought that trying to send data over a closed socket is a Bad Thing™ and that your program needs to be notified immediately, and since nobody ever checks error codes, what better way to notify you than to send a signal?