# Sending files over TCP sockets C++ | Windows

Tags: c++, winsock, winsock2, winsockets

I want to send files over TCP sockets in C++ on Windows, all is working absolutely fine, however I can't send big files like this, I understand that TCP as any protocol has it's limitations, like I can't send more than 64KB per packet, my method works for small file sizes(tested all up to 12KB), but I would like to send LARGE files, like iso image of ubuntu or windows, which are surely bigger than 12 fully packed packets and etc.

Server

```
int filesize = 0;
int err = recv(conn, (char*)&filesize, sizeof(filesize), 0);
if (err <= 0)
{
    printf("recv: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    clean(conn);
}
printf("recv %d bytes [OK]\n", err);

char* buffer = new char[filesize];
ZeroMemory(buffer, filesize);
err = recv(conn, buffer, filesize, MSG_WAITALL);
if (err <= 0)
{
    printf("recv: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    clean(conn);
}
printf("recv %d bytes [OK]\n", err);

ofstream file("a.txt", ios::binary);
file.write(buffer, filesize);
delete[] buffer;
file.close();
```

Client

```
ifstream file("a.txt", ios::binary);
file.seekg(0, ios::end);
int size = file.tellg();
file.seekg(0, ios::beg);
char* buffer = new char[size];
file.read(buffer, size);
file.close();

int* fsize = &size;
int err = send(client, (char*)fsize, sizeof(int), 0);
if (err <= 0)
{
    printf("send: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
}
printf("send %d bytes [OK]\n", err);

err = send(client, buffer, size, 0);
if (err <= 0)
{
    printf("send: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
}
printf("send %d bytes [OK]\n", err);
delete[] buffer;
```

All values for both sides are initialised, and error handling is done well, and if I had problem then I would have said about that. I decided to use MSG_WAITALL because I guess that is suitable for this case, please correct my code for recieving/sending and if possible refactor it, it would be nicer if it would be with explainations, so that evrybody could learn to code better, thanks)))

Comment: Unrelated  `MSG_WAITALL` on a large file can be a mistake. Consider using a loop instead.

Comment: You might want to look at [TransmitFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mswsock/nf-mswsock-transmitfile) for streaming a file over a socket.

Comment: OK. Reading closer, that's part of the problem. Try looping on `recv`s with  a moderately-sized buffer, say 4K, and immediately write what you get to the filestream. Keep looping until you've received and written `filesize`bytes.

Comment: Also, if you are looking to `send` more than 2GB, you might need to use an type longer than `int` for your "size" parameter.  Like uint64_t.

Comment: @user4581301, So give an example why this is bad. It's waiting until buffer is filled, what makes my life easier so that I don't have to handle recieving buffer, paddings, overflows, packet lengths and over stuff...

Comment: @selbie Will correct it

Comment: The buffer backing the TCP socket might not be able to hold `filesize` bytes of data and you have pretty much zero control over the size of that buffer.

Comment: @user4581301, That would work but sending is harder, how do I read next 4096 elements from buffer or replace first 4096 ones, idk

Comment: Because it's a stream, `ofstream` takes care of the sequential writes. Every new block of data will be appended to whatever you have written before.

Comment: @user4581301, This is why I am trying to move to sending file in chunks of 4KB or more, but I am still stuck with this.

Comment: There are plenty of examples if you do some searching on "send file to socket". [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594042/c-send-file-to-socket/5594250)

Comment: It's not "bad" per se to invoke `send` with `MSG_WAITALL`.  It's just that you won't have any way to monitor or log progress for that file transfer.  Considering sending in either 100KB or even 1MB chunk.

Comment: This is just how sockets works. When you try to read or write N bytes from a socket, you have no guarantees whatsoever that this many bytes will be read or written. Fewer than that may be read or written, in which case you must try again. Even `recv(conn, (char*)&filesize, sizeof(filesize), 0);`, where `filesize` is an `int`, is not guaranteed to give you `int` bytes.

Comment: Consider using ftp. ftp is based on TCP.  If you 'want' to rewrite what ftp can already do, consider investigating an existing ftp client sw.

Comment: "*I can't send more than 64KB per packet*" What do you mean by "per packet"? Your code doesn't manipulate packets anywhere.

Comment: I don't know why this was closed. The "duplicate" is not C++ and doesn't deal with large files. It's just a simple solution in C that deals with small files less than 2.1 GB. OP specifically asked for file transfers larger than 2.1 GB and to use C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The one main point that should be taken away from the comments below your question is that `send` and `recv` are fickle. Just because you write `send(buffer with 100 bytes)` doesn't mean it's going to send 100 bytes. It could send 25 bytes, or 99 bytes, or fail out completely. It's up to you to take the return value and compute what needs to still be sent.

Same goes with `recv`. If you write `recv(buffer with 100 bytes)` because you are expecting 100 bytes, it could only grab 25 bytes, or 99 bytes, or fail out completely. Again, it's up to you to use that return value and compute what still needs to be received.

File I/O is completely different. If you want to write 100 bytes to a file, those 100 bytes are guaranteed to be written if the method doesn't fail. So, when folks who have worked with file I/O move to socket I/O usually end up confused why things aren't sending or receiving correctly.

One of the trickier parts to socket programming is knowing how much data you will need to receive. You covered that by sending the length of the file first. The server will know to read in that value, then continue reading until that value is satisfied.

Some protocols, like HTTP, will use delimiters (in HTTP's case `\r\n\r\n`) to signal when a packet of data has ended. So, as a socket programmer, you would `recv` on a loop until those 4 bytes are read.

I put together an example on how you could accomplish sending and receiving a large file (this will handle files up to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 in length). This isn't pure C++, I cheated in places because of lack of time. I used some Windows-only constructs for the same reason.

So let's take a look at it:

```
int64_t GetFileSize(const std::string& fileName) {
    // no idea how to get filesizes > 2.1 GB in a C++ kind-of way.
    // I will cheat and use Microsoft's C-style file API
    FILE* f;
    if (fopen_s(&f, fileName.c_str(), "rb") != 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    _fseeki64(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    const int64_t len = _ftelli64(f);
    fclose(f);
    return len;
}

///
/// Recieves data in to buffer until bufferSize value is met
///
int RecvBuffer(SOCKET s, char* buffer, int bufferSize, int chunkSize = 4 * 1024) {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < bufferSize) {
        const int l = recv(s, &buffer[i], __min(chunkSize, bufferSize - i), 0);
        if (l < 0) { return l; } // this is an error
        i += l;
    }
    return i;
}

///
/// Sends data in buffer until bufferSize value is met
///
int SendBuffer(SOCKET s, const char* buffer, int bufferSize, int chunkSize = 4 * 1024) {

    int i = 0;
    while (i < bufferSize) {
        const int l = send(s, &buffer[i], __min(chunkSize, bufferSize - i), 0);
        if (l < 0) { return l; } // this is an error
        i += l;
    }
    return i;
}

//
// Sends a file
// returns size of file if success
// returns -1 if file couldn't be opened for input
// returns -2 if couldn't send file length properly
// returns -3 if file couldn't be sent properly
//
int64_t SendFile(SOCKET s, const std::string& fileName, int chunkSize = 64 * 1024) {

    const int64_t fileSize = GetFileSize(fileName);
    if (fileSize < 0) { return -1; }

    std::ifstream file(fileName, std::ifstream::binary);
    if (file.fail()) { return -1; }

    if (SendBuffer(s, reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&fileSize),
        sizeof(fileSize)) != sizeof(fileSize)) {
        return -2;
    }

    char* buffer = new char[chunkSize];
    bool errored = false;
    int64_t i = fileSize;
    while (i != 0) {
        const int64_t ssize = __min(i, (int64_t)chunkSize);
        if (!file.read(buffer, ssize)) { errored = true; break; }
        const int l = SendBuffer(s, buffer, (int)ssize);
        if (l < 0) { errored = true; break; }
        i -= l;
    }
    delete[] buffer;

    file.close();

    return errored ? -3 : fileSize;
}

//
// Receives a file
// returns size of file if success
// returns -1 if file couldn't be opened for output
// returns -2 if couldn't receive file length properly
// returns -3 if couldn't receive file properly
//
int64_t RecvFile(SOCKET s, const std::string& fileName, int chunkSize = 64 * 1024) {
    std::ofstream file(fileName, std::ofstream::binary);
    if (file.fail()) { return -1; }

    int64_t fileSize;
    if (RecvBuffer(s, reinterpret_cast<char*>(&fileSize),
            sizeof(fileSize)) != sizeof(fileSize)) {
        return -2;
    }

    char* buffer = new char[chunkSize];
    bool errored = false;
    int64_t i = fileSize;
    while (i != 0) {
        const int r = RecvBuffer(s, buffer, (int)__min(i, (int64_t)chunkSize));
        if ((r < 0) || !file.write(buffer, r)) { errored = true; break; }
        i -= r;
    }
    delete[] buffer;

    file.close();

    return errored ? -3 : fileSize;
}
```

> Sending and Receiving Buffers

At the top we have two methods that works with buffers in memory. You can send it any buffer at any size (stay reasonable here), and those methods will send and receive until all the bytes passed in have been transmitted.

This does what I was talking about above. It takes the buffer and loops until all the bytes have been successfully sent or received. After these methods complete, you are guaranteed that all data is transmitted (as long as the return value is zero or positive).

You can define a "chunk size" which is the default size of the chunks of data the methods will use to send or receive data. I am sure these can be optimized by using more suitable values than what they are currently set at, but I don't know what those values are. It's safe to leave them at the default. I don't think that with the speed of today's computers you will notice too much of a difference if you change it to something else.

> Sending and Receiving Files

The code for doing files is almost identical in nature to the buffer code. Same idea, except now we can assume that if the return value is greater than zero from the buffer methods then it was successful. So the code is a little simpler. I use a chunk size of 64KB... for no special reason. This time the chunk size determines how much data is read from the file I/O operations, not the sockets I/O.

> Test Server and Client

Just to be complete, I used this code below to test this with a 5.3 GB file I have on disk. I basically just re-wrote Microsoft's [client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/complete-client-code)/[server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/complete-server-code) examples in a very slimmed down way.

```
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#include <iostream>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <fstream>

DWORD __stdcall ClientProc(LPVOID param) {

    struct addrinfo hints = { 0 }, * result, * ptr;
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    if (getaddrinfo("127.0.0.1", "9001", &hints, &result) != 0) {
        return ~0;
    }

    SOCKET client = INVALID_SOCKET;
    for (ptr = result; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->ai_next) {
        client = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype, ptr->ai_protocol);
        if (client == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            // TODO: failed (don't just return, cleanup)
        }
        if (connect(client, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            closesocket(client);
            client = INVALID_SOCKET;
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }
    freeaddrinfo(result);

    if (client == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        std::cout << "Couldn't create client socket" << std::endl;
        return ~1;
    }

    int64_t rc = SendFile(client, "D:\\hugefiletosend.bin");
    if (rc < 0) {
        std::cout << "Failed to send file: " << rc << std::endl;
    }

    closesocket(client);

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);

    {
        struct addrinfo hints = { 0 };
        hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
        hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
        hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
        hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

        struct addrinfo* result = NULL;
        if (0 != getaddrinfo(NULL, "9001", &hints, &result)) {
            // TODO: failed (don't just return, clean up)
        }

        SOCKET server = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);
        if (server == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            // TODO: failed (don't just return, clean up)
        }

        if (bind(server, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen) == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            // TODO: failed (don't just return, clean up)
        }
        freeaddrinfo(result);

        if (listen(server, SOMAXCONN) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            // TODO: failed (don't just return, clean up)
        }

        // start a client on another thread
        HANDLE hClientThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ClientProc, NULL, 0, 0);

        SOCKET client = accept(server, NULL, NULL);

        const int64_t rc = RecvFile(client, "D:\\thetransmittedfile.bin");
        if (rc < 0) {
            std::cout << "Failed to recv file: " << rc << std::endl;
        }

        closesocket(client);
        closesocket(server);

        WaitForSingleObject(hClientThread, INFINITE);
        CloseHandle(hClientThread);
    }
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```