# Connection reset by peer socket error when the client terminate connection during write()

Tags: c++, sockets, websocket

I have my server sending a large file to client(web browser) but when i refresh my page i am getting the **conection reset by peer error** and the program terminates. What i am expecting is server get a new connectiont.

```
 while (true)
    {
        check((new_socket = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address,

                                   (socklen_t *)&addrlen)),
              "accept_failed");
        read(new_socket, buffer_recv, 1024);
        printf("%s\n", buffer_recv);
        T = std::thread(handle_connection, new_socket);
        T.detach();
    }
```

handle_connection contains

```
while (file.read(&buffer[0], 1024))
    {
        s = file.gcount();
        content = chunk::make_chunk(buffer, s);
        check(write(new_socket, &content[0], content.size()), "Write_error");
    }
```

where check being simple error handling function and make_chunk return string.How can i make the server from not exiting and continue listening for connection please answer i am new to socket programming

Comment: If this is the sum total of  the code on your "web server", then something is definitely missing -- it appears to be that the shown code does not actually implement any part of HTTP. It's either that, or the shown code fails to meet the requirements of a [mre], as explained in the [help], and because of that it won't be possible for anyone to help you.

Comment: On Linux SIGPIPE signal can be generated when writing to a socket in certain scenarios causing the application to terminate by default. You can try `send(new_socket, &content[0], content.size(), MSG_NOSIGNAL);` instead of `write` to maybe get the error code instead of the signal.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `setsockopt(SO_NOSIGPIPE)` on the new socket, then you can continue using `read()` and `write()`, and not have to specify `MSG_NOSIGNAL` on every `recv()` and `send()`. See [How to prevent SIGPIPEs (or handle them properly)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108183/).

Comment: @RemyLebeau  MSG_NOSIGNAL worked thank you . is there a way to terminate the thread rather than killing the whole process.

Comment: @ArjunUS that is the whole point of disabling SIGPIPE. That will cause socket I/O operations to just fail with error codes that you can handle normally in your code, like breaking loops and exiting thread procedures, rather than killing your process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `send()` with `MSG_NOSIGNAL` or you can set `SO_NOSIGPIPE` socket option with `setsockopt()`. But with the minimal change in the existing code and for applying the settings to all the created sockets, You can do something like this:

From the man page of [`write()`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html)

> `EPIPE` :  fd is connected to a pipe or socket whose reading end is closed. When this happens the writing process will also receive a SIGPIPE signal.  (Thus, the write return value is seen only if the program catches, blocks or ignores this signal.)

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main()
{
    /* .... */

    sigset_t sigmask;

    sigemptyset(&sigmask);
    sigaddset(&sigmask, SIGPIPE);

    if (sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &sigmask, NULL) != 0)  // get EPIPE instead
        goto handle_sigprocmask_fail;

    /* .... */

    int wr_return = write(sockfd, buf, sizeof(buf));

    if (wr_return == -1) {
        if (errno == EPIPE)
            goto handle_epipe;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you Mohith  MSG_NOSIGNAL worked for me. how can i terminate the current thread rather than killing the whole process when this signal happens

Comment: @ArjunUS What is the need now, you wont be getting the SIGPIPE anymore.

Comment: From ``signal`` man page : A signal may be process-directed or thread-directed.  A process-directed signal is one that is targeted at (and thus pending for) the process as a whole.  A signal may be process-directed because it was generated by the kernel for reasons other than a hardware exception, or because it was sent using kill(2) or sigqueue(3).  >>

Comment: A thread-directed signal is one that is targeted at a specific thread.  A signal may be thread-directed because it was generated as a consequence of executing a specific machine-language instruction that triggered a hardware exception (e.g., SIGSEGV for an invalid memory access, or SIGFPE for a math error), or because it was targeted at a specific thread using interfaces such as tgkill(2) or pthread_kill(3).

Comment: I don't have clear picture about signal, My doubt is whether the send function keeps on writing to socket even after we close the client should we handle that case

Comment: @ArjunUS Sounds like ``SIGPIPE`` is process directed, so it is placed in the process signal queue instead of thread signal queue, therefore we dont know which thread is responsible for generating ``SIGPIPE``

Comment: @ArjunUS The harsh truth is yes, you need to handle that case, Refer to this link [why write() generates SIGPIPE instead of just giving -1 when receiving end is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216374/why-is-writing-a-closed-tcp-socket-worse-than-reading-one/2218360#2218360)